# remove a character from the entire data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with various columns, Some of the data within some columns contain double quotes, I want to remove these, for eg:

```
ID    name   value1     value2
"1     x     a,"b,"c     x"
"2     y     d,"r"       z"
```

I want this to look like this:

```
ID    name   value1    value2
1     x      a,b,c      x
2     y      d,r        z
```

Comment: What is the code you used to read this into R? You probably just need a minor adjustment

Comment: Try `df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern='"', replacement='')`

Comment: @ akrun, Thanks this worked!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would use `lapply` to loop over the columns and then replace the `"` using `gsub`.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, gsub, pattern='"', replacement='')
df1
#  ID name value1 value2
#1  1    x  a,b,c      x
#2  2    y    d,r      z
```

and if need the `class` can be changed with `type.convert`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, type.convert)
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(ID = c("\"1", "\"2"), name = c("x", "y"),
value1 = c("a,\"b,\"c", 
"d,\"r\""), value2 = c("x\"", "z\"")), .Names = c("ID", "name", 
"value1", "value2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: +1 for assignment using square brackets (`df[] <-`) to coerce `lapply`'s returned list to a data frame.  I never knew that trick.

Comment: @drammock Thank's, The `[]` can be used whenever we want to return the structure of the old dataset for the replaced values.

Comment: This didnt work for me: `data[] <- lapply(data, gsub, pattern = '$', replacement = '')`...when I type `str(data) all of the "$" are still present...

Comment: @zsad512  I don't know about your data.  The example data in my post works for me

Comment: @zsad512 Downvoting a working answer because your data is different is not good.  First you need to understand the difference between a metacharacter i.e. `$` and a nonmetacharacter.  Just looking at an answer and then complaining that it is not working and then downvoting is absolutely unfair.

Comment: Is there an option to do this with dplyr in R?

Comment: @LDT you can do `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(across(everything(), str_remove_all(., '"')))`

Comment: I had problems running the suggestion of @akrun, error: `"argument is not an atomic vector"` . This worked for me: `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(across(everything(), str_remove_all, pattern = '"'))`

Comment: @Smerla Sorry, i forgot to add the `~` for lambda i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_remove_all(.x, '"')))`

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `apply()` along with the `gsub()` function to remove all double quotation marks:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("\"1", "\"2"),
                 name=c("x", "y"),
                 value1=c("a,\"b,\"c", "d,\"r\""),
                 value2=c("x\"", "z\""))

df <- data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) {
                                  x <- gsub("\"", "", x)
                              })

> df
  ID name value1 value2
1  1    x  a,b,c      x
2  2    y    d,r      z
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove `$` you have to escape it `\\\$`. Try:

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern="\\\$", replacement="")
```

Comment: The double backslash, `\\$`, is the escape character not the triple backslash.

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr solution (based on the suggestion of @akrun in one of the comments).

```
df1 <-  structure(list(ID = c("\"1", "\"2"), name = c("x", "y"),
                       value1 = c("a,\"b,\"c", "d,\"r\""),
                       value2 = c("x\"", "z\"")),
                      .Names = c("ID", "name", "value1", "value2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df1 <- df1 %>% dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), stringr::str_remove_all, pattern = '"'))
```